# Trying to find the most efficient way to convert SQL Query to Pandas DataFrame that has large number of records

Tags: python, sql, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I am trying to query MS-SQL database view and convert the result to Pandas DataFrame.

Below are the two different ways I tried and in both cases it is taking ~439.98 seconds (~7 minutes) in order to query and convert to DataFrame that has **415076 records** (This time is for converting it to the DataFrame, not for data retrieval). This is a typical case in the data input/retrieval part of my application business logic for user request.

Note: For queries that have fewer records (say in x1000's) the query result to DataFrame conversion performance is fast in both cases.

```
query = """ SELECT * 
            FROM db_view_name 
            WHERE CONDITION_1 = %d AND
            CONDITION_2 IN (%s) """ %(int(val), ','.join(map(str, my_values_list)))
con = pyodbc.connect(con_string)

Case 1:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(query)
    items = [dict(zip([key[0] for key in cursor.description], row)) for row in result]
    df = pd.DataFrame(items)

Case 2:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
```

**My Environment:** I am using Python 3.6 with Pyramid web framework and SQLAlchemy ORM.

How can I reduce the time it takes to process these many records? Any help on this problem will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: For clarification, can you confirm that it is not the data retrieval but the conversion into a dataframe that is taking this much time?

Comment: I Updated that in description, Thanks @Thornhale

Comment: Try `from_records` avoiding *items* build: `pd.DataFrame.from_records(result, columns=[key[0] for key in cursor.description])`

Comment: @Parfait I tried with from_records but still it is taking the same time for execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference to others (we already talked about this).

The slow part in the lines of code above is the conversion of the SQL return to a pandas data frame. This step is not only slow but single-threaded given Python's default behavior.

To get around this behavior, one way to bruteforce the processing is to send x subqueries in separate processes.

Once we have the results of the subquery, assembly of individual dataframes via pd.concat is actually fast.

Since you are looking at parallelizing tasks, consider the following "distributed computing" libraries:

- Dask: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/
- Distarray: http://docs.enthought.com/distarray/
- Ray: https://ray-project.github.io/2017/05/20/announcing-ray.html

All enable you to parallelize tasks with a bit more automation if you are willing to trade in adding another libraries to your list of dependencies.

The alternative is to either use multi-process functionalities within Python core itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughts @Thornhale